# How to export sqlite database as csv file in android?

Tags: java, android

i am trying to print the content's in the table from the database .so i am trying to generate a csv file from database.. any  inputs on how to do this  always appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

copy the db to your local computer.
use sqlite3 to query and redirect the output to a text file.

```
sqlite> .mode list
sqlite> .separator ,
sqlite> .output test_file_1.txt
sqlite> select * from yourtable;
sqlite> .exit
```

http://www.sqlite.org/sqlite.html